# When does Amtrak assign reserved seats?

Tags: tickets, amtrak

I just booked my first Amtrak ticket ever for a trip in mid-September, and the email I got says I have "1 reserved coach seat," but I don't see a seat number or anything to give me a unique seat anywhere. When, if ever, will that happen? Do I get emailed an assignment as the trip gets closer, do I get one when I present my ticket at the gate, etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The distinction between a "reserved coach seat" and an "unreserved coach seat" is that they (sort of) guarantee that there will be seats for all passengers with "reserved" seats but not for passengers with "unreserved" coach seats.  From the Amtrak website (bolding mostly mine):

[Reserved Coach Seat:](https://www.amtrak.com/onboard/onboard-accommodations-for-all-your-needs/seating-accommodations/reserved-coach.html)

> While reserved coach seating is available on our long distance routes and many trains that travel short / medium distance routes, the train cars are different depending on where a train travels, so some of the amenities are different as well.  ... Advance reservations (by train, **not by individual seat**) are required.*

[Unreserved Coach Seat:](https://www.amtrak.com/onboard/onboard-accommodations-for-all-your-needs/seating-accommodations/unreserved-coach.html)

> Only a few short-distance trains have unreserved coach seating, where tickets are valid on any train unless restricted by the fare paid.
>
> **While seating is not guaranteed**, unreserved coach seats have most of the features that reserved coach seats have...

The trains that have unreserved coach seats are Auburn (CA)–Sacramento–San Jose;  Milwaukee–Chicago;  Philadelphia—Harrisburg;  and San Luis Obispo–Santa Barbara–LA–San Diego.  I would guess that these lines are often used by commuters who want a little more flexibility in their train times.

As to how the boarding experience works:  You get on the train, find a seat, and stow your luggage.  Occasionally, the conductors will direct you to particular cars depending on your destination as you walk up to the train on the platform.  Once the train is underway again, the conductors will go through the cars and ask all new passengers to show their tickets.

---

**Editorial note, May 2019:*  when I wrote this answer in 2015, the Amtrak guidelines at at the time followed this sentence with, "Once you make your reservation, a seat is guaranteed."  This sentence is no longer on the current version of the page, which strikes me as mildly suspicious.

Comment: The Sacramento-San Jose, California train is indeed popular with commuters (only a few trains per day go to Auburn). Not only to commuters want flexibility, Amtrak sells a 10-ride ticket at a significant discount to 10 single tickets, and holders of that ticket just board whichever train they please. I have never seen a train literally standing room only, but it could happen.

Comment: Chicago-Milwaukee (the *Hiawatha*) is also used for commuters, as well as for air travellers who like to fly to a quiet airport (General Mitchell in Milwaukee) and then hop on a train, and not worry so much about which, and for tourists from Chicago who want to catch a Cubs game at a reasonable rate (@Brewers) or just play around town.  It's treated like a Metra (interurban type commuter line) similar to what @AndrewLazarus described.

Comment: When I rode Amtrak Cascades I was almost always assigned a seat at a podium in Seattle and Portland before boarding. Their web site says no assigned seats though.

Answer (score 5):

The term "reserved seat" is not to be taken too literally. It just means that the train will not overbook, and they have reserved "some" seat for you, but not a specific one.

Source: Having used Amtrak two years ago with such a "reserved seat" on an east-coast train between DC and New York.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike European railroads and most airlines, Amtrak never issues specific seat reservations, on any train. Even if riding in the Acela's pricey first class, it is first-come, first served.  Generally, this is less of a problem for the solo traveler, but it can be a major complication for the couple or family that understandably wants to sit together.  The nearest exception I can think of is in the case of sleeping accommodations, in which one reserves a specific room.  The reasons Amtrak give for this policy don't withstand analysis, and given that the option of specific reservations at extra cost are a revenue source for European carriers, they make even less sense.  Certainly, the needless queuing and mad rush for seats at many train stations diminishes the appeal of rail travel in this country.

Comment: This is not quite accurate. Amtrak does not assign seats in advance, but on long-distance routes, the attendant does have some latitude to direct you to a particular seat at the time of travel, for instance, to allow a family to sit together, or to minimize nighttime disturbance. On the NEC, most passengers are only traveling for a couple of hours, and many objected to assigned seating when they attempted to introduce it on the Acela, because they were used to open seating like we had on the Metroliner. Amtrak may try to reintroduce assigned seating now that electronic collection is in place.

Comment: FWIW, Amtrak introduced assigned seating for first class on Acela Express trains at the end of May 2018, though these remain the only assigned seats you can get in the system.